# Passing has value from view to controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, will-paginate

Hey guyz I want to pass a value from view with will_paginate and want to access this value in controller as params[:user][:id]. How will I do it?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you are doing? You cannot pass values from the view to the controller, first the controller is executed and then the view is rendered. You can however, set parameters in the views (like the form parameters) that will be processed by the controller once the form is submitted.

Comment: @rorra ya I know that. But Since i m using will_paginate plugin in rails, so there is need to pass some variables so that controller processing can be done.

Comment: but when you use will_paginate, and you click on any page link, it should pass the param **page**, so you will see something like **http://mywebsite.com/my_resources?page=3**. If you by chance are doing any other operation like a form submission, just add the hidden field **page**, like **<%= hidden_field_tag 'page', params[:page] %>. What is exactly your problem, what you need to pass from the view to the controller and what's the behavior you want to archive?

Comment: Ok u tell me how to pass double has value from form_tag, which i can access as params[:user][:is]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want to do:

```
<%= will_paginate @user_rep, params: { start_date: @start_date, end_date: @end_date, user: @user.attributes.to_hash } %>
```

or if you want to do it by hand

```
<%= will_paginate @user_rep, params: { start_date: @start_date, end_date: @end_date, user: { id: @user_id } } %>
```

Comment: In Second statement, would i able to access 3rd parameter as params[:user][:id]?

Comment: From the controller, yes, you will be able to do **params[:user]** which will return a hash, and the only item has the key **id**, so **params[:user][:id]** will give you the user id. On the first statement, you are just passing all the data for the user. You can also just pass the user id, like **<%= will_paginate @user_rep, user_id: user.id %>** and then on the controller you just access **params[:user_id]**